# Can I avoid reaction delay (nearly 1s) in web pages on iPhone 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

## Question

Is there any way, perhaps hardware acceleration, or WebGL, or *anything*, anything, I can do to speed up touch reaction speed on iPhone? I would really like the reaction to appear instant.

## My problem

I noticed that my menu was taking nearly a full second to react to its icon being tapped on an iPhone 6, while the menu reacts instantly to a click on desktop. I notice this seems to be the case with all the mobile websites I visited for testing, and the ~1s delay is really bothersome, it takes away that crisp, reactive feel from the web application. Installed applications on iOS, on the other hand react instantly to touch, so I know it isn't the touch detection speed.

## Example

I created an example to test this out:

```js
var size = 'norm';
var $box = $('#box').on('click', function () {
    if (size == 'norm') {
        $box.css({
            'width' : '1in',
            'height' : '1in'
        });
        size = 'big';
    } else {
        $box.css({
            'width' : '',
            'height' : ''
        });
        size = 'norm';
    }
});
```

```css
#box {
    width:0.5in;
    height:0.5in;
    margin:0.5in;
    background-color:violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Tap the box on an iPhone and you'll see what I mean.

## What I've tried

I tried inserting `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` into the item's style to activate hardware acceleration, but this didn't seem to improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

use a light weight plugin that eliminate the click delay such as fastClick
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: I see, mobile browser vendors purposely add a `300ms` delay to check to see if it's a double tap, but that's a poorly considered idea. Instead, why not give the developers the power to decide which elements should listen for a double tap?

Comment: true perception. there are also mobile-friendly events that you can fall back to such as tap, touchstart, touchend that have no delay and give better control

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is an intentional delay in mobile browsers to differentiate touches from swipes. This is a well documented issue, and fortunately, there are plenty of workarounds to choose from:

- [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) is a drop-in library that is meant to remove this issue across multiple devices and browsers.
- [Mobile Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away?hl=en) has a means of turning off the delay. Firefox has a similar method, and IE has a CSS flag for it.
- You can register the `touchstart` event instead of the `click` event.

[Telerik has a fairly recent article regarding your options](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8/) for the current state of mobile browsers (2015).